# snap and SMART errors when attaching external drive

Tags: external-hdd, snap, smart

When I plug in my external USB hard-drive to my Lubuntu 16.04 system, it mounts, unmounts, mounts, unmounts, finally succeeds.

I see errors associated with `snap` and SMART in the syslog immediately after plugging the drive in:

```
Jun  1 09:45:05 /usr/bin/snap[29746]: cmd.go:114: DEBUG: not restarting into "/snap/core/current/usr/bin/snap" ([VERSION=2.24 2.24]): older than "/usr/bin/snap" (2.25)
Jun  1 09:45:05 udisksd[1880]: Error performing initial housekeeping for drive /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/WDC_WD2500AAJS_75M0A0_WD_WMAV2Z383248: Error updating SMART data: sk_disk_smart_read_data: Operation not supported (udisks-error-quark, 0)
Jun  1 09:45:06 /usr/bin/snap[29764]: cmd.go:114: DEBUG: not restarting into "/snap/core/current/usr/bin/snap" ([VERSION=2.24 2.24]): older than "/usr/bin/snap" (2.25)
Jun  1 09:45:07 kernel: [1380062.722240] EXT4-fs (sdd1): recovery complete
```

How can I fix these errors?

Comment: The snap messages aren't errors, they're just debug messages and can really be ignored.

Comment: I would use the "disks" utility to test the disk.

Comment: Apparently SMART is not supported over USB for this disk.  I think that is root of the problem.  I need to stop the system from polling for SMART data somehow.

Comment: Do you have `gsmartcontrol` installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `lsusb` detects a **JMicron Technology** bridge, you have your answer. Some of them are not fully compatible with SMART and this causes the error unfortunately.

Comment: You nailed it! I looked in `syslog` and it showed the JMicron device.

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm glad it helped!