# WD Easystore 8TB won't stay mounted

Tags: usb, hard-drive

I'm running ubuntu server and I'm having an issue with my new WD Easystore 8TB external USB hard drive.  I've reformatted the device from ntfs to ext4 and successfully mounted the drive to `/data`.  Then I launch a screen session and begin rsync my 1TB NAS to it, also mounted via nfs.  Everything goes pretty well for the first couple of hours, but then the drive suddenly disappears.  Doesn't show up in df, blkid, or fdisk.

I'm getting the following out of my dmesg.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

mounted in `/etc/fstab` as

```
# boot wd external
UUID=74e77482-49a1-4f94-ae5e-410d2542e242 /data ext4    defaults        0       0

# Worldbook
192.168.1.148:/nfs/Public /home/brombomb/Public nfs nolock,rw,intr 0 0
```

[dmesg - pastebin](https://pastebin.com/hivR3F69)

When I have it initially plugged in here are the relevant bits:

`blkid`

```
/dev/sdb1: UUID="74e77482-49a1-4f94-ae5e-410d2542e242" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="30d87852-6cbd-4787-b24e-121203770b71"
```

`fdisk -l`

```
Device     Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 15628052446 15628050399  7.3T Linux filesystem
```

`lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 006: ID 1058:25fb Western Digital Technologies, Inc.
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 28de:1142
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp.
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`lsblk`

```
19:30:38]terra:~> sudo lsblk
NAME                 MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                    8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1                 8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                 8:2    0   488M  0 part /boot
└─sda3                 8:3    0 930.5G  0 part 
  ├─terra--vg-root   253:0    0 922.6G  0 lvm  /
  └─terra--vg-swap_1 253:1    0     8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sdb                    8:16   0   7.3T  0 disk 
└─sdb1                 8:17   0   7.3T  0 part /data
```

Comment: Something to check: https://askubuntu.com/questions/921114/snap-and-smart-errors-when-attaching-external-drive

Comment: updated post with `lsub` info.

Comment: What does 'lsblk' say?

Comment: @byteborg added `lsblk` info